# Masking some value inside Json string in Java

Tags: java, json, regex

Suppose i have below Json String:

```
{   
    "name":"noor",
    "pass":"12345" 
}
```

I want to mask pass value using Regex, like below

```
{
    "name":"noor",
    "pass":"*****" 
}
```

How i can do it, using Java regex?

Comment: What have you tried in the way of a regular expression? Have you done the  regular expressions tutorial at (any number of sites)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`"pass":"(.*?)"`

As seen on: https://regex101.com/r/cK4bD0/1

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
String jsonString = "{ \"name\":\"noor\", \"pass\":\"12345\" }";

String result = jsonString.replaceAll("(?<=pass\":\")(.*?)(?=\")", "*****");

System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

```
{[^}]*"pass"\s*:\s*"(.*?)"[^}]*}
```

Here is the DEMO:  https://regex101.com/r/nL3tP2/2